# I am looking Spring Boot + Spring Social + Spring Session(Redis) example.Does anybody have link?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-social, spring-session

I am looking Spring Boot + Spring Social  + Spring Session(Redis) example.Does anybody have link?

Spring Boot 1.2.3-Release and latest social + Spring security

Comment: Check [here](http://drissamri.be/blog/2015/05/21/spring-security-and-spring-session/) for Spring Session with Redis and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-boot) for Spring Social with Boot. Otherwise, just [Google](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=Spring+Boot+%2B+Spring+Social+%2B+Spring+Session&oq=Spring+Boot+%2B+Spring+Social+%2B+Spring+Session)

Comment: There isn't going to be a tutorial for every possible combinations of frameworks out there. Check the spring social sample, add the spring session sample and you should be good to go.

Comment: There is an example using Spring Boot + Spring Session + Spring Security. Here you [go](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application). I would follow @M.Deinum 's advice, start with a few basic components and keep adding other components later on. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This would a good start I hope..
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2014/11/externalizing-session-state-for-spring.html